# What is the characteristic of a field in lay terms?

Tags: soft-question, field-theory

And why do we usually assume a field has characteristic not equal to 2?

Comment: Usually because in a number of domains, properties may depend on it. For instance quadratic forms.

Comment: Very often (example, coding theory) we work in a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Bananaspace is probably referring to analysis problems like in Linear Algebra, where we need that assumption

Comment: In lay terms, a field is a place where you grow crops or play a ball game and its characteristics might be things like the type of soil or whether the turf is natural. If you've read the definition of a field and read the definition of its characteristic and read enough to see results where the characteristic is not equal to $2$ and wonder why, I don't think you're a lay person!

Comment: @RobArthan I'm self-learning and know the definitions, but sometimes knowing the technical definition doesn't help you see the bigger picture and stands in the way of proper learning, so that's why I'm asking. I apologize if this wasn't the appropriate question for this site.

Comment: No need to apologise. I apologise if I made you uneasy: I was just trying to boost your confidence in a light-hearted way $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 4):

In layman's terms, it's the amount of times we can keep adding 1 to itself without looping back to 0.   The characteristic being $p$ means that $1+1+....+1 (p times)=0$.   It's defined to be 0 if this never loops (so adding 1 to itself multiple times never loops back to 0).

Lots of weird stuff happens in fields of characteristic 2, because everything its its own additive inverse, since $1+1=0$, we have $x+x=0$,  or $x=-x$.   A TON of proofs end up with a step where in order to show something is 0,  you show its equal to its own additive inverse....and that means it's 0, UNLESS the field is of characteristic 2.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic of a field is basically the first natural number which is equal to 0 in that field. Thus, if the field has characteristic $p$, then you can't divide by $p$ in the field. We often assume the characteristic is not 2 simply so we can divide by 2. This is necessary for the quadratic formula to hold, for instance.

Comment: Equivalently, the principal generator of the kernel of the unique unital ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to F$. (One has a canonical choice of generator in $\Bbb Z$: the nonnegative one.)

Comment: @whacka I'm pretty sure that answer is the exact opposite of "In lay terms" :)

Comment: Indeed. :-) ${}$